# How do i iterate this object of array using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angular-directive

I have this following object of array returned in my console now what i want to do is to iterate it over using ng-repeat in my index.html file so how will i do it here is the returned json:-

```
{body: ["xx", "x", "x", "vinit↵", "gyghg", "hjhghg", "j", "jj", "bn", "ss"]}
```

My app.js:-

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('movie',['$http','$scope',function($http,$scope) {
    $scope.products = [];
    $http.get('blog/').then(successCallback, errorCallback);
    function successCallback(response){
        products=response.data;
        console.log(products);
    }
    function errorCallback(error){
        console.log(error);
    }

    // body...
}]);
```

And here what i am doing to iterate those objects in my index.html:-

```
<div ng-repeat="item in products">
    <ul>
        <li>{{item.body}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But Its not printing anything on the screen what i want is to print those array element in that li tag.

Comment: change `products=response.data;` to `$scope.products=response.data;`

Comment: I think there is no need to do that ,since i have already declared $scope.products=[ ].

Comment: Do this, ng-repeat="item in products.body" it should work

Comment: @VinitRaj but, while you reassign it, you need `$scope.` there. or `products=response.data` will create a normal JS variable called `products` and assign your value to that

Comment: @VinitRaj check my answer

Comment: Yes i got it @tanmay, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module("app", []).controller('Controller', Controller);

    function Controller($scope, $http) {
      var res =  {body: ["xx", "x", "x", "vinit↵", "gyghg", "hjhghg", "j", "jj", "bn", "ss"]};
      $scope.products = res.body;
    }

  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller" class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="item in products track by $index">
      <ul>
        <li>{{item}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Required to Change `products=response.data;` to  `$scope.products=response.data;`

Assign response value to angular scope variable to access that value in html page.

And change {{item.body}} to {{item}}

```
    <li>{{item}}</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a $scope variable products,

change

**From**

```
 products=response.data;
```

**To**

```
 $scope.products=response.data;
```

and you should be able to access in ,

```
<div ng-repeat="item in products">
    <ul>
        <li>{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: But my question is how i will  access those elements of array using ng-repeat so that i can get correct values in my <li> tag

Answer (score 1):

Change `products=response.data;` To  `$scope.products=response.data;`

And change {{item.body}} to {{item}}

```
<div ng-repeat="item in products">
    <ul>
        <li>{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As everybody tells you, you need to replace

```
products=response.data;
```

to

```
 $scope.products=response.data;
```

After that, in the view, you want to iterate the body elements, so:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in products.body">
<ul>
    <li>{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('movie',['$http','$scope',function($http,$scope) {
$scope.products = [];
$http.get('blog/').then(successCallback, errorCallback);
function successCallback(response){
    $scope.products=response.data;
    console.log($scope.products);
}
function errorCallback(error){
    console.log(error);
}

// body...
}]);
```